# searching a csv file and then outputting a term associating to the term

Tags: python, csv

I am creating a code, that read a csvs file and search for a specific item code and then it will output the name of the item.
How would i do this?
I don't have any code yet

Thanks

Comment: `python` tag without code?. Please post what you've done.

Comment: Python, sorry i thought open csv, means read csv

Comment: Try pandas.read_csv.  Give it a shot and come back when you have a code example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/tutorials.html)

Install it, then try

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('yourFile.csv')
print df
```